# Mysql - Returning table name in select query result

Tags: mysql, select

[Database Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbkxk.png)
I have a database that stores a bunch of info including the username, password and other details of different types of users (admin, customers etc.) in seperate tables of course.

And I want to search through the database using the username and return the name of the table that username belongs to. This will tell me what type of user they are.
Something like this:

SELECT tableName FROM table1,table2,table3
WHERE username= thisValue

I don't have much experience with mysql so I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Begin by redesigning your table structure.  Have *one* table with user information and include a column for something like a "user type".  (Even better, a lookup table of user types and have a foreign key to that table.)  The structure you have now is difficult to query and maintain, as you're discovering.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the database layout for reference

Answer (score 1):

You said `in seperate tables of course`, but in practice it would probably be better to just have a single user table, with a `role` column which records the user's role:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    role_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id)
)
```

and a `roles` table:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    desc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

With this design in place, it would be fairly straightforward to find all users who are, e.g., admins:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN roles r
    ON u.role_id = r.id
WHERE
    r.desc = 'admin';
```

This answer assumes that a given user would only always have a single role.  To account for multiple roles, we could use a junction table between the `users` and `roles` tables.

Comment: The problem is each different user relates to the database in different ways and has different attributes. The tables included in the database are: Admin, Customer, Festival Organiser, Festival, Booking, Ticket, Performer and Performer_Festival. The only attributes each user shares are username and password

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the database layout for reference

Comment: This new information won't really change my answer.